# How to create stubs of C++ code with the same classes/signatures as in given dll?

Tags: c++, dll, java-native-interface

For some test needs I need some third-party dll to be replaced with own stubbed version: the actual methods should return some hard-coded data with some specific delays and delays' effect on the system that uses the original dll are actually the under the test.

So, for this purpose I need some how to create a *.cpp file with the same structs and signatures  from the dll. What is the best approach to do it programmatically?

1) decompilers? but actually I don't need the code itself, just class definitions and signatures only.

2) do it programmatically with c++ code

3) do it programmatically with java code through JNI, for example.

Any ideas and directions are welcome. Unfortunately, googling doesn't give the straighforward answer, at least for c++ newbies as me.

Comment: You hopefully have the header files for the public API implemented by the 3rd-party DLL. This issue has been addressed on SO before: _[Automatically generate C++ file from header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404614/automatically-generate-c-file-from-header)_ - try [Lazy C++](http://www.lazycplusplus.com/).

Comment: actually, NO. just dll and some code that uses in via jni (may be based on header files but not the header files itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this DLL is loaded from Java and called via JNI, then you can launch [javah](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javah.html) to produce the relevant headers; <s>use `-stubs` option to prepare the **C** files with dummy implementations of all native methods</s>.

**Update**: `-stubs` does not work correctly, see *[Unable to generate JNI .c file using javah -stubs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410016/unable-to-generate-jni-c-file-using-javah-stubs)*